# Obtaining different APP key in URL for FB share button

Tags: php, html, facebook-share

I am integrating Fb share button in my website. Here the code which I am using to integrate FB share button:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http://<?php echo $url; ?>&layout=button&size=small&appId=123456789422&width=59&height=20" width="59" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

When I click on FB share button, it will show the AppId in URL which is used in the facebook developer documentation not my AppId which I have used in my code. Here is the doc link [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)/ . All is working fine. But I can't understand why it is showing documentation App key as shown in this link: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4107554/fd8726c7d3270b58f0a27f7fd9498d47 .Is anything I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You specified `appId=123456789422` as parameter in the iframe URL, so that’s the app id it will use for sharing …

Comment: @04FS you mean to say that AppId or App_key is different from one another?

Comment: App id and app key are the same thing, yes.

Comment: If I pass appId=123456789422 statically then it will show screen with myappname
that "Log in to use your Facebook account with "Appname".

Comment: What do you mean, it was pretty much “static” before already in the code you have shown? _“then it will show screen with myappname Log in to use your Facebook account with "Appname"”_ - when/where? When you try to share, or when you try to login to your app using its login button? Please make a bit more of an effort to _properly_ explain what your situation is, what exactly you implemented and how.

Comment: Means when you hit fblogin button it redirects to the url in which app_key is defined. I copied that URL and replace the app_key with my app_key and hit the url then it will show fblogin screen with myapp name which I required.

Comment: _“which I required”_ - so you got what you required now? Then what is the problem?

Comment: @04FS bro it is not dynamic. By default, I required my AppId in URL on clicking FB share button

Comment: Well then output it in that place _dynamically_, if that’s what you want …? I really have no idea what you are even trying to ask here now.

Comment: I am saying that when I passed my app id in code then it does not come. But when I copied the url from the share popup and changed the app id then It worked fine. Means correct app id is not coming through code.

Comment: So show the relevant code then.

Comment: I already posted the code above

Comment: Then I am even more clueless now as to what your actual problem is. I’m gonna give up here at this point, it seems rather fruitless to continue this discussion, if you can not manage to provide a proper explanation of what your issue is to begin with.

Comment: No problem. thanks for your help.